# Chord Recognition Training

Tags: piano, chords, notation, sheet-music

I'm an amateur piano player trying to progress toward more difficult material and it seems what is slowing me down the most is identifying what chord I'm looking at on the sheet music, especially when it isn't in root position.

I'm trying to find something - a set of flash cards, an app, etc. that will give me something like this:

[image]

Where I would respond with C Major 1st Inversion and keep iterating in this fashion. If there is an elegant tool out there that does this, I would love to be pointed in the right direction. Or, if someone has a good way to practice this, I'd accept that too.

Comment: https://www.musictheory.net/exercises/chord

Comment: @trw I've looked that over, but that seems to be identify the quality of the chord rather than what the chord's name is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the exact answer you asked for.

12 chord roots x 3 chord qualities (major, minor, diminished) x 3 inversions = 108 cards.

If you only did major and minor, it's 72 cards.

Approximately 100 cards is not too much. You could make a set on index cards.

Just make sure you include a *clef*. Your example assumes treble clef, but the clef should be provided.

If you do make your own cards, a thing to consider is whether to include a key signature or use accidentals on the chord notes without a key signature. In other words, if the chord is `B` major, use a `B` major key signature and write the chord without accidentals on the notes. That will better reflect actual notation reading and also provide a built-in quiz of key signatures.

Comment: Good suggestion, but 15 roots would be better to account for the enharmonic keys.

Comment: Good point. That would make a very complete set.

Answer (score 2):

Get a hymnbook from your local Protestant church and study the chords therein.  You'll find inversions and passing chords.

Comment: But don‘t sreal it!

Answer (score 2):

Here are seventh chord flashcards: https://music-theory-practice.com/chords/seventh-chord-flashcards.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to NAME it, you need to PLAY it.   Your best 'flash cards' will be a constant supply of music to sight-read.

Comment: The only downside is all the beginner stuff only uses a few keys so you don't get to read lots of spellings. Of course the flip side is first reading a small set of keys and gradually progressing to more.